# Loop keeps returning the same integer

Tags: javascript

Can any of you guys explain to me why my loop keeps returning the same integer? I personally have no idea why it isn't a random integer.

Kind Regards..

CODE:

```
var currentTry = 2;

for(;;){
    var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random * 100) + 1;

  if(1/currentTry*100 < randomInt){
    currentTry = currentTry+1;
  }else{
    console.clear();
    console.log("This took me: " + currentTry + " tries!");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What integer would that be?

Comment: I'm trying to change the (var) currentTry integer.

Comment: Change `Math.random` to `Math.random()`

Comment: That made hella sense, thank you so much :)

I have no idea why it wasn't Math.random().

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random * 100) + 1;
```

will evaluate to `NaN`. That's why the `if` is never entered. `Math.random` is a function not a variable so you should call it like this `Math.random()`. Here is what you should do:

```
var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
```

Comment: I just noticed, I've looked over this piece of code like a hundred times but couldn't find the issue, it was so easy.. thank you for your anwser anyways :)